# iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in

Tags: php

this error apper in execl sheet when i download it from website.

**Notice:  iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in C:\xampp\htdocs\servay2\controllers\SurveyResultsController.php on line 63**

i use Arabic language in DB.

```
        $headers = [];
        foreach ($survey->questions as $question) {
            $headers[] = iconv('UTF-8', 'WINDOWS-1252', $question->question_text);
        }

        fputcsv($fp, $headers);

        foreach ($survey->responses as $response) {
            $row = [];
            foreach ($survey->questions as $question) {
                $field = 'question_' . $question->question_id;
                $row[] = iconv('UTF-8', 'WINDOWS-1252', $response->$field);
            }
            fputcsv($fp, $row);
        }
```

Comment: The warning tells you to look at the string encoding (figure out which input, do a hexdump etc.)

Comment: Can you explain more please? I am a beginner